# moment js get date until current hour

Tags: timestamp, momentjs

Lets say the current date is "2020-07-26 19:01:53" But I want this date:
"2020-07-26 19:00:00" 
How can I get that date?
I have used this code but I only get an error:

```
 moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH').unix()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to use the [startOf](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) function like this:

```
moment().startOf('hour').unix()
```